# Change first line of CSV file to all uppercase

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a set of csv files, and for each file, the first line contains column names for a data set. Some csv files have all upper case column names, others have all lower case column names. My question is how do I change every csv file so that the first line of each file (aka the column names) displays as all uppercase strings in each column?

My attempt at it was the following:
first, I manually checked all the files to see which ones had column names that were uppercase and lowercase, then I ran the following commands:

```
head -1 uppercase.csv > header.csv
#repeated all commands below for all lowercase files individually
sed -i 1d lowercase.csv 
cat header.csv lowercase.csv > lowercase_new.csv
rm lowercase.csv
mv lowercase_new.csv lowercase.csv
```

I want to know if there is a more automated way to do this, without going through each file manually.

#### Examples:

**Dataset1.csv**

```
a b c
x x x
```

**Dataset2.csv**

```
A B C
y y y
```

How do I make **Dataset1.csv** look like the following?

```
A B C
x x x
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you. I will repost on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. Don't want to completely delete this post since a lot of people answered the question.

Comment: This is not OT here, its just missing your attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following simple `awk` may help you in same too.

```
awk 'NR==1{$0=toupper($0)} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** 
`NR==1`: checking condition here if it is first line then do following:

`$0=toupper($0)` Making current line's value as UPPER CASE and saving to it.

`1` `awk` works on method of condition and then action so I am making condition TRUE here and not mentioning any action here so by default printing of current line will happen.

In case you want to save the output into Input_file itself then append following to above solution `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file`. Where Input_file is your data file which you want to change or pass to `awk`.

Comment: Finally - a sensible answer!

Comment: @EdMorton, a THANKS from THE Ed sir, you made my day sir :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with **sed**:

```
$ sed -i -e '1 s/\(.*\)/\U\1/' input.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to point out the obvious, your commands can perfectly well be put into a script and executed on a set of files.

```
#!/bin/sh

head -n 1 uppercase.csv > header.csv

for lowercase; do
    sed -i 1d "$lowercase"
    cat header.csv "$lowercase" > "$lowercase"_new
    rm "$lowercase"
    mv "$lowercase"_new "$lowercase"
done

rm -f header.csv
```

Save it as `headerfix`, then make it executable with `chmod +x ./headerfix`, then run it with `./headerfix lower1.csv lower2.csv lower3.csv` to fix the headers in those three files.

A proper production script would use properly randomized temporary file names (use `mktemp`) and take care to clean them out even if it was interrupted, too (use `trap`); and I guess the entire loop body could be refactored into a single `sed` script (in which case, no loop necessary) but you already have good answers which do that elegantly.

Comment: thanks for this answer! I am basically a linux n00b so I had no idea you could do something like this in bash

Comment: Actually, it used to be one of the selling points for the Borne shell. Anything you can do on the command line can be put in a script, and vice versa. You still see the old style e.g. in Windows batch script where some parts of the syntax is different in the interactive shell (though I guess they finally fixed that in Powershell).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `awk` for this purpose:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{ print toupper($0) }NR>1' Dataset1.csv
```

**Explanations:**

for the first line (`NR==1`) will change the whole line `$0` to uppercase then for the rest of the file (`NR>1`) will do its default action which is printing the line.

Now if you want to generate a file just redirect `stdout`

```
$ awk 'NR==1{ print toupper($0) }NR>1' Dataset1.csv > new_file.csv
```

or if you want to edit the initial file do something like:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{ print toupper($0) }NR>1' Dataset1.csv > tmp.csv && mv tmp.csv Dataset1.csv
```

Another completely different approach would combine `tr`, `tail` and `head` in one command:

```
$ cat toUpper.csv 
a b c
x x x 
y y y
z z z

$ (head -1 toUpper.csv | tr [[:lower:]] [[:upper:]] && tail -n +2 toUpper.csv ) > new_file.csv

$ cat new_file.csv 
A B C
x x x 
y y y
z z z
```

Comment: thanks for the remark! I have checked the manual and the online doc and you are right!!! sorry -> Editing my post